# How do I ignore file deletions in a git branch for merging purposes?

Tags: git, merge

Given an example project structure like:

```
 /project
    /ui
       front-endy-files.htmls
       other-stuff-to-keep.js
    server.py
    other.py
```

What I would like to do is:

1. create new branch for designer from master
2. delete files not needed by designer (server code e.g. *.py)
3. give designer access... *magic happens*
4. merge branch back into master ignoring the deletion of the server code i.e. I only want to get the merge of new code after I've done the "clean up" (step #2) i.e. the `server.py` file in master should not be deleted on merge of the branch even though `server.py` was deleted in branch.

I know I could cherry-pick the commits but I'm wondering if there's another git-ish way of doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git is not designed for what you are looking to do.  If you want to prevent access to portions of your codebase look into using a submodule.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Your workflow would result in over complications, especially as I imagine that there will be other people working on the files that you are deleting from the designer.

You could also not delete the files and examine the merge for changes to unrelated files via `git diff --name-only <branch> master`.  Particularly if those other files are necessary for the designer to test the work that they are doing.

Comment: It's not so much about limiting access (they would have the other branches too) but just stripping the extraneous code from the branch and making some other changes.

They're not going to be able to run the full stack required by the API for a number of reasons, so I'm providing a mocked API implementation, different READMEs for setup etc.. (again part of changes I dont want merged back in)

Comment: I would still recommend the submodule for the code that they are going to be modifying.  Provide the mocked API and have them commit in the submodule.  Then you can update your repo without having to pull things out or remembering to change anything.