# Merge branches, except for file moves and deletions, with git

Tags: git, git-merge

Is there a way when merging with git not to merge file moves and deletions?

We've made a branch and then trimmed down the branch by deleting or moving a large number of files. There have also been a number of modifications made in that branch to the reorganized files. What I now want to do is merge back to the full branch the changes made to the trimmed-down directory, but still keep all the files that were deleted in the trimmed-down branch, and keep all of the files in their original locations.

Is there an easy way with git to merge back the changes from the trimmed-down branch, while not doing any of the file deletions or moves? Preferably one that can easily handle the fact that the modified files have been moved.

Note that I'm primarily concerned with the content of the changes, rather than the branch history, so approaches which use cherry-picking or rebasing are fine. (As long as I don't have to manually trawl through the commit history to isolate those commits with modification changes.)

*I found [How do I ignore file deletions in a git branch for merging purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166368/how-do-i-ignore-file-deletions-in-a-git-branch-for-merging-purposes), but the question there is prospective, and the answer is "don't do that". In my situation the branching and deletion has already occurred.*

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something I would do in Git. There is probably a way to do it, but I would do this with some shell scripting instead. You didn't specify your environment, but my solution will be for a UNIX environment. There should be tools for running bash scripts regardless.

First, if your branches have diverged so that you have changes on both the branches you want to "merge", you probably want to do a rebase. Lets call your branches `master` and `deletions`. If you have pushed `deletions` so that someone else is working on that branch, I would probably create a new identical branch `deletions2` that I would rebase on `master` to avoid rewriting the history. You probably don't want to continue working on `deletions` anyways since you would have to redo it all, but this way you won't destroy anything.

Then I would copy all files from `deletions2` to `master` manually by cloning the repo and check out one branch in one copy of the repo and the other branch in the other copy. Then I would list all the tracked files and copy them using a simple loop:

```
deletions2/ $ \
git ls-tree HEAD -r | while read f; do \
    # use -n to keep master versions, -f to keep deletions versions, \
    # or -i to choose manually for each file \
    cp -f "$f" ../master/ \
done
```

Comment: One problem is that the modifications have been done to files which have been moved. So the files are not in the same location in the `deletions` branch and `master` branch.

Comment: Ok, then I have no idea how to do this. I guess it's time for me to learn patching and similar. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I handled it.

As with user2882096's answer, I'll use the convention that the full, pre-deletion branch is `master`, and the trimmed branch is `deletions`. I'll also assume that you're working out of the root directory of the repository.

First off, git gets confused really easily by moved files, so the first thing is to reverse the moves in a sacrificial branch.

```
git checkout -b deletions2 deletions
git merge-base deletions2 master # Note this SHA1 - substitute it in the following commands
git diff --diff-filter=R -M25% --raw SHA1 | awk '{system("mkdir -p `dirname " $(NF-1)"`; git mv " $NF " " $(NF-1) )}'
git commit
```

The git diff command uses diff-filter to pull out just the renames (moves) that have happened just on the deletions branch. The -M25% means to do a more extensive rename detection, looking for files which have up to 75% modification in addition to being moved. The --raw changes the output format to one which is more convenient for post processing.

The awk command is just a way to reverse the move. (Note that this isn't necessarily robust if you have spaces or funky characters in the filenames.) The only complication here is that `git mv` will not create a directory that doesn't exist, hence the `mkdir -p basename` bit.

With the moves undone, we can get a patch for the modifications and additions (but not deletions):

```
git diff --patch --diff-filter=AM -M25 SHA1 > modifications.patch
```

We can then make another sacrificial branch at the merge point to allow us to apply the changes.

```
git checkout -b temp SHA1
git apply modifications.patch # and resolve any issues
git merge master # To resolve conflicts with the current state of master
```

Now we simply merge the temporary branch back into master.

```
git checkout master
git merge temp
```

That will merge the modifications, but not the commit history. If you also want the commit history merged in:

```
git merge -s ours deletions2
```

Where the `-s ours` tells git merge to merge the commit histories, but keep the state of the files as they currently are.

*Final note: It might be nicer if instead of using `git diff` and `git apply` to make the patches, you used `git format-diff` and `git am`. However, I was unable to make it work well with the --diff-filter option. The appropriate patches are made, but they don't apply cleanly. Someone more familiar with the two might have better success.*